# Can we use "paypal payment method" for indian shopping website

Tags: paypal, payment

We are planning to use "paypal payment method" as payment option for indian shopping site.

Assume Indian customers (buyers of products) have paypal account & Owner/admin of the site have paypal account.

Is it possible to use"paypal" in indian shopping sites?

If so, is it possible to pay use "online net banking through paypal" for all banks?

Please guide me.

Comment: Is your problem solved, did you integrate PayPal for Indian website?

Comment: @Rathinam yes, i did......

Comment: I connected by using API Signature, but PayPal option does not display for my website front end at select payment option,

Comment: Actually, my base currency INR, is any cause base currency INR?

Comment: @Rathinam i am also using base currency as INR , please check some configuration again by following [link](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bdp1WaabGeqG8QeDjbPACA&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+configure+paypal+)

Comment: Is everything fine, details also looking good, still not PayPal option not shown at the website, and also there is no error in log files.

Comment: @Rathinam than if you post new question with all details about what and all you already tried, than hopefully you get a solution soon......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, it's possible to use PayPal Payment Method for Indian sites as well, You need a merchant's account in PayPal to receive the money from Customers using PayPal as well.
- You cannot have Net Banking (Customer will pay through their personal bank's internet banking facility) integrated with PayPal.
- You need to create a different Payment Method to offer your customers Net Banking Payment facilities.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. means using paypal, indian customers can pay through their credit cards and debit cards [all indian banks] somewhere, I heard "Is government of india blocked paypal in indian shopping site"?
but why most of the top indian sites[flipkart] are not using paypal option in the site.

Comment: Yes, customers can pay through PayPal, but, the govt. still have lots of restrictions, so store owners like, flipkart or other prefer direct payment through net banking. And another point is we Indians are still feel comfortable with Net Banking rather than a third party payment gateway (PayPal).